# php Redirect url to a Ifram

Tags: javascript, php, payment-gateway

Please accept my apology in advance if my question is long.
I am using a payment gateway of woocommerce.

When click on checkout it goes to an external link. Then there We have button to click and Then It goes to another link which make it enable to pay via cards.

Now What I want to do is that.
I want to minimize some step.
1- If possible I want to bypass detail page which appears after click on Checkout button.

2- Is this possible to hide amount on detail page. As my website currecny is different and this payment gateway the show in different.

3- If above 1,2 not possible. Can simply put external pages in a iframe.
So if user click on check out. It should show a ifram on new page current page with redirected link.

Below code is from gateway plugin.

```
<?php

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'init_pp_woo_gateway');

function mib_ppbycp_settings( $links ) {
    $settings_link = '<a href="'.admin_url( 'admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=checkout&section=mibwoo_pp' ).'">Setup</a>';
    array_push( $links, $settings_link );
    return $links;
}
$plugin = plugin_basename( __FILE__ );
add_filter( "plugin_action_links_$plugin", 'mib_ppbycp_settings' );

function init_pp_woo_gateway(){

    if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Payment_Gateway' ) ) return;

    class WC_Gateway_MIB_PayPro extends WC_Payment_Gateway {

        // Logging
        public static $log_enabled = false;
        public static $log = false;

        var $merchant_id;
        var $merchant_password;
        var $test_mode;
        var $plugin_url;
        var $timeout;
        var $checkout_url;
        var $api_url;
        var $timeout_in_days;

        public function __construct(){

            global $woocommerce;

            $this -> plugin_url = WP_PLUGIN_URL . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'woocommerce-paypro-payment';

            $this->id                   = 'mibwoo_pp';
            $this->has_fields           = false;
            $this->checkout_url         = 'https://marketplace.paypro.com.pk/';
            $this->icon                 = 'https://thebalmainworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Credit-Card-Icons-copy-1.png';
            $this->method_title         = 'Paypro';
            $this->method_description   = 'Pay via Debit/Credit card.';

            $this->title                = "Paypro";
            $this->description          = "Pay via Debit/Credit card.";
            $this->merchant_id          = $this->get_option( 'merchant_id' );
            $this->merchant_password    = trim($this->get_option( 'merchant_password' ));
            $this->merchant_secret      = $this->get_option( 'merchant_secret' );
            $this->test_mode            = $this->get_option('test_mode');
            $this->timeout_in_days      = $this->get_option('timeout_in_days');
            $this->debug                = $this->get_option('debug');
            $this->pay_method           = "Paypro";
            if($this->timeout_in_days==='yes'){
                $this->timeout              = trim($this->get_option( 'merchant_timeout_days' ));
            }
            else{
                $this->timeout              = trim($this->get_option( 'merchant_timeout_minutes' ));
            }
            if($this->test_mode==='yes'){
                $this->api_url              = 'https://demoapi.paypro.com.pk';
            }
            else{
                $this->api_url              = 'https://api.paypro.com.pk';
            }

            $this->init_form_fields();
            $this->init_settings();

            self::$log_enabled = $this->debug;

            // Save options
            add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );

            // Payment listener/API hook
            add_action( 'woocommerce_api_wc_gateway_mib_paypro', array( $this, 'paypro_response' ) );

        }

        function init_form_fields(){

            $this->form_fields = array(

                'enabled' => array(
                    'title' => __( 'Enable', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'type' => 'checkbox',
                    'label' => __( 'Yes', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'default' => 'yes'
                ),

                'merchant_id' => array(
                    'title' => __( 'Merchant Username', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'description' => __( 'This Merchant Username Provided by PayPro', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'default' => '',
                    'desc_tip'      => true,
                ),

                'test_mode' => array(
                    'title' => __( 'Enable Test Mode', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'type' => 'checkbox',
                    'label' => __( 'Yes', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'default' => 'yes'
                ),

                'merchant_password' => array(
                    'title' => __( 'Merchant Password', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'type' => 'password',
                    'description' => __( 'Merchant Password Provided by PayPro', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'default' => __( '', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'desc_tip'      => true,
                ),

                'merchant_secret' => array(
                    'title' => __( 'Secret Key', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'type' => 'password',
                    'description' => __( 'Any Secret Key Or Word with No Spaces', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'default' => __( rand(), 'woocommerce' ),
                    'desc_tip'      => true,
                ),

                'merchant_timeout_minutes' => array(
                    'title' => __( 'Timeout (In Minutes)', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'type' => 'number',
                    'description' => __( 'Timeout Before order expires it can be between 5 to 30 minutes', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'default' => __( 5, 'woocommerce' ),
                    'desc_tip'      => true,
                    'custom_attributes' => array(
                        'min' => 5,
                        'max' => 30
                    )
                ),

                'timeout_in_days' => array(
                    'title' => __( 'Enable Timeout in days', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'type' => 'checkbox',
                    'label' => __( 'Yes', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'default' => 'no'
                ),

                'merchant_timeout_days' => array(
                    'title' => __( 'Timeout (In Days)', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'type' => 'number',
                    'description' => __( 'Minimum 1 day Max 3 Days. Remember, It works as due date you\'ve selected 1 day the expiration date of the PayPro id will be set as the day after today.', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'default' => __( 1, 'woocommerce' ),
                    'desc_tip'      => true,
                    'custom_attributes' => array(
                        'min' => 1,
                        'max' => 3
                    )
                ),

                'debug' => array(
                    'title'       => __( 'Debug Log', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'type'        => 'checkbox',
                    'label'       => __( 'Enable logging', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'default'     => 'no',
                    'description' => sprintf( __( 'Debug Information <em>%s</em>', 'woocommerce' ), wc_get_log_file_path( 'paypro' ) )
                ),
            );
        }
        /**
         * Logging method
         * @param  string $message
         */
        public static function log( $message ) {
            if ( self::$log_enabled ) {
                if ( empty( self::$log ) ) {
                    self::$log = new WC_Logger();
                }

                $message = is_array($message) ? json_encode($message) : $message;
                self::$log->add( 'paypro', $message );
            }
        }


        /**
         * Process the payment and return the result
         *
         * @access public
         * @param int $order_id
         * @return array
         */
        function process_payment( $order_id ) {

            $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

            $paypro_args = $this->get_paypro_args( $order );

            $paypro_args = http_build_query( $paypro_args, '', '&' );
            $this->log("========== Payment Processing Started: args =========");
            $this->log($paypro_args);

            //if demo is enabled
            $checkout_url = $this->checkout_url;;
            return array(
                'result'    => 'success',
//                'redirect'    => 'http://localhost:8000/secureform?'.$paypro_args
                'redirect'  => 'https://marketplace.paypro.com.pk/secureform?'.$paypro_args
            );

        }


        /**
         * Get PayPro Args for passing to PP
         *
         * @access public
         * @param mixed $order
         * @return array
         */
        function get_paypro_args( $order ) {
            global $woocommerce;

            $order_id = $order->get_id();

            //Encrypting the username and password
            $token1         = $this->merchant_id;
            $token2         = $this->merchant_password;
            $cipher_method  = 'aes-128-ctr';
            $secret_word    = md5($this->merchant_secret);
            $enc_key        = openssl_digest($secret_word.date('d/m/y'), 'SHA256', TRUE);
            $enc_iv         = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher_method));
            $crypted_token1 = openssl_encrypt($token1, $cipher_method, $enc_key, 0, $enc_iv) . "::" . bin2hex($enc_iv);
            $crypted_token2 = openssl_encrypt($token2, $cipher_method, $enc_key, 0, $enc_iv) . "::" . bin2hex($enc_iv);
            unset($token, $cipher_method, $enc_key, $enc_iv);

            // PayPro Args
            $paypro_args = array(
                'mid'                   => $crypted_token1,
                'mpw'                   => $crypted_token2,
                'secret_public'         => base64_encode($this->merchant_secret),
                'is_encrypted'          => 1,
                'mode'                  => $this->test_mode,
                'timeout_in_days'       => $this->timeout_in_days,
                'merchant_order_id'     => $order_id,
                'merchant_name'         => get_bloginfo( 'name' ),
                'request_is_valid'      => 'true',
                'request_from'          => 'woocommerce',

                // Billing Address info
                'first_name'            => $order->get_billing_first_name(),
                'last_name'             => $order->get_billing_last_name(),
                'street_address'        => $order->get_billing_address_1(),
                'street_address2'       => $order->get_billing_address_2(),
                'city'                  => $order->get_billing_city(),
                'state'                 => $order->get_billing_state(),
                'zip'                   => $order->get_billing_postcode(),
                'country'               => $order->get_billing_country(),
                'email'                 => $order->get_billing_email(),
                'phone'                 => $order->get_billing_phone(),
            );
            if (!function_exists('is_plugin_active')) {
                include_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php');
            }
            if(is_plugin_active( 'custom-order-numbers-for-woocommerce/custom-order-numbers-for-woocommerce.php' )){
                $paypro_args['paypro_order_id']             = time().'-'.get_option( 'alg_wc_custom_order_numbers_counter', 1 );
            }
            else{
                $paypro_args['paypro_order_id']             = time().'-'.$order_id;
            }
            // Shipping

            if ($order->needs_shipping_address()) {
                $paypro_args['ship_name']               = $order->get_shipping_first_name().' '.$order->get_shipping_last_name();
                $paypro_args['company']                 = $order->get_shipping_company();
                $paypro_args['ship_street_address']     = $order->get_shipping_address_1();
                $paypro_args['ship_street_address2']    = $order->get_shipping_address_2();
                $paypro_args['ship_city']               = $order->get_shipping_city();
                $paypro_args['ship_state']              = $order->get_shipping_state();
                $paypro_args['ship_zip']                = $order->get_shipping_postcode();
                $paypro_args['ship_country']            = $order->get_shipping_country();
            }

            $paypro_args['x_receipt_link_url']  = $this->get_return_url( $order );
            $paypro_args['request_site_url']    = get_site_url();
            $paypro_args['request_site_checkout_url']   = wc_get_checkout_url();
            $paypro_args['return_url']          = $order->get_cancel_order_url();
            $paypro_args['issueDate'] = date('d/m/Y');
            $paypro_args['cartTotal'] = $order->get_total();
            $paypro_args['store_currency'] = get_woocommerce_currency();
            $paypro_args['store_currency_symbol'] = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();

            //Getting Cart Items
            $billDetails= array();
            $flag = 0;
            foreach ($order->get_items() as $item => $values){
                // Get the product name
                $product_name = $values['name'];
                // Get the item quantity
                $item_quantity = $order->get_item_meta($item, '_qty', true);
                // Get the item line total
                $item_total = $order->get_item_meta($item, '_line_total', true);
                $price = $item_total/$item_quantity;
                $billDetails[$flag]['LineItem'] = esc_html($product_name);
                $billDetails[$flag]['Quantity'] = $item_quantity;
                $billDetails[$flag]['UnitPrice'] = $price;
                $billDetails[$flag++]['SubTotal'] = $item_total;
            }
            $paypro_args['cartItemList'] = urlencode(json_encode($billDetails));
            ////

            //setting payment method
            if ($this->pay_method)
                $paypro_args['pay_method'] = $this->pay_method;

            //if test_mode is enabled
            if ($this -> test_mode == 'yes'){
                $paypro_args['test_mode'] = 'Y';
            }
            //if timeout_in_days is enabled
            if ($this -> timeout_in_days == 'yes'){
                $paypro_args['timeout'] = $this->timeout;
            }
            else{
                $paypro_args['timeout'] = $this->timeout*60;
            }

            $paypro_args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_paypro_args', $paypro_args );

            return $paypro_args;
        }


        /**
         * this function is return product object for two
         * different version of WC
         */
        function get_product_object(){
            return $product;
        }


        /**
         * Check for PayPro IPN Response
         *
         * @access public
         * @return void
         */
        function paypro_response() {


            global $woocommerce;

            // woocommerce_log($_REQUEST);

            $this->log(__("== INS Response Received == ", "PayPro") );
            $this->log( $_REQUEST );

            $wc_order_id = '';

            if( !isset($_REQUEST['merchant_order_id']) ) {
                if( !isset($_REQUEST['vendor_order_id']) ) {
                    $this->log( '===== NO ORDER NUMBER FOUND =====' );
                    exit;
                } else {
                    $wc_order_id = $_REQUEST['vendor_order_id'];
                }
            } else {

                $wc_order_id = $_REQUEST['merchant_order_id'];
            }

            $this->log(" ==== ORDER -> {$wc_order_id} ====");

            // echo $wc_order_id;
            $wc_order_id = apply_filters('woocommerce_order_no_received', $wc_order_id, $_REQUEST);
            $this->log( "Order Received ==> {$wc_order_id}" );
            // exit;


            $wc_order       = new WC_Order( absint( $wc_order_id ) );
            $this->log("Order ID {$wc_order_id}");

            $this->log("WC API ==> ".$_GET['wc-api']);
            // If redirect after payment
            if( isset($_GET['key']) && (isset($_GET['wc-api']) && strtolower($_GET['wc-api']) == 'wc_gateway_mib_paypro') )  {
                $this->verify_order_by_hash($wc_order_id);
                exit;
            }

            $message_type   = isset($_REQUEST['message_type']) ? $_REQUEST['message_type'] : '';
            $sale_id        = isset($_REQUEST['sale_id']) ? $_REQUEST['sale_id'] : '';
            $invoice_id     = isset($_REQUEST['invoice_id']) ? $_REQUEST['invoice_id'] : '';
            $fraud_status   = isset($_REQUEST['fraud_status']) ? $_REQUEST['fraud_status'] : '';

            $this->log( "Message Type/Fraud Status: {$message_type}/{$fraud_status}" );

            switch( $message_type ) {

                case 'ORDER_CREATED':
                    $wc_order->add_order_note( sprintf(__('ORDER_CREATED with Sale ID: %d', 'woocommerce'), $sale_id) );
                    $this->log(sprintf(__('ORDER_CREATED with Sale ID: %d', 'woocommerce'), $sale_id));
                    break;

                case 'FRAUD_STATUS_CHANGED':
                    if( $fraud_status == 'pass' ) {
                        // Mark order complete
                        $wc_order->payment_complete();
                        $wc_order->add_order_note( sprintf(__('Payment Status Clear with Invoice ID: %d', 'woocommerce'), $invoice_id) );
                        $this->log(sprintf(__('Payment Status Clear with Invoice ID: %d', 'woocommerce'), $invoice_id));
                        add_action('woocommerce_order_completed', $order, $sale_id, $invoice_id);

                    } elseif( $fraud_status == 'fail' ) {

                        $wc_order->update_status('failed');
                        $wc_order->add_order_note(  __("Payment Declined", 'woocommerce') );
                        $this->log( __("Payment Declined", 'woocommerce') );
                    }

                    break;
            }

            exit;
        }


        function verify_order_by_hash($wc_order_id) {

            global $woocommerce;

            @ob_clean();

            $paypro_id  = $_REQUEST['paypro_id'];
            $tpaycode   = $_REQUEST['tpaycode'];
            $order_id   = $_REQUEST['merchant_order_id'];
            $wc_order       = wc_get_order( $wc_order_id );
            // $order_total = isset($_REQUEST['total']) ? $_REQUEST['total'] : '';
            $order_total    = $wc_order->get_total();

            $compare_string =  $this->merchant_id . $paypro_id . $order_total;
            $compare_hash1 = strtoupper(md5($compare_string));
            $this->log("Compare String ===>" .$compare_string);
            $compare_hash2 = $_REQUEST['key'];
            if ($compare_hash1 != $compare_hash2) {
                $this->log("Hash_1 ==> {$compare_hash1}");
                $this->log("Hash_2 ==> {$compare_hash2}");
                wp_die( "PayPro Hash Mismatch... check your secret word." );
            } else {
                //Curl Request
                $url = $this->api_url.'/cpay/gos?userName=' . $this->merchant_id . '&password=' . $this->merchant_password . '&cpayId=' . $tpaycode;
                $ch = curl_init($url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
                // Submit the GET request
                $result = curl_exec($ch);
                if (curl_errno($ch))  //catch if curl error exists and show it
                    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
                else {
                    //Check if the order ID passed is the same or fake
                    $res = json_decode($result, true);
                    $returnedOrderID = explode('-',$res[1]['OrderNumber']);
                    if ($returnedOrderID[1]===$order_id) {
                        if (strtoupper($res[1]['OrderStatus']) == "PAID") {

                            $wc_order->add_order_note( sprintf(__('Payment completed via PayPro Order Number %d', 'paypro'), $tpaycode) );
                            // Mark order complete
                            $wc_order->payment_complete();
                            // Empty cart and clear session
                            $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
                            $order_redirect = add_query_arg('paypro','processed', $this->get_return_url( $wc_order ));
                            // Close cURL session handle
                            curl_close($ch);
                            wp_redirect( $order_redirect );
                            exit;

                        } elseif (strtoupper($res[1]['OrderStatus']) == "BLOCKED") {
                            $wc_order->add_order_note( sprintf(__('Error processing the payment of Order Number %d', 'paypro'), $tpaycode) );
                            $order_redirect = add_query_arg('paypro','canceled', $wc_order->get_cancel_order_url());
                            // Close cURL session handle
                            curl_close($ch);
                            wp_redirect( $order_redirect );
                            exit;
                        }
                        elseif (strtoupper($res[1]['OrderStatus']) == "UNPAID") {
                            $wc_order->add_order_note( sprintf(__('Error processing the payment of Order Number %d', 'paypro'), $tpaycode) );
                            $order_redirect = add_query_arg('paypro','pending', $wc_order->get_cancel_order_url());
                            // Close cURL session handle
                            curl_close($ch);
                            wp_redirect( $order_redirect );
                            exit;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function get_price($price){

            $price = wc_format_decimal($price, 2);

            return apply_filters('mib_get_price', $price);
        }

    }

}

function add_mib_payment_gateway( $methods ) {
    $methods[] = 'WC_Gateway_MIB_PayPro';
    return $methods;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'add_mib_payment_gateway' );


function payproco_log( $log ) {

    if ( true === WP_DEBUG ) {
        if ( is_array( $log ) || is_object( $log ) ) {
            $resp = error_log( print_r( $log, true ), 3, plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'payproco.log' );
        } else {
            $resp = error_log( $log, 3, plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'payproco.log' );
        }

        var_dump($resp);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using this pluging on this website. https://boriband.com/